# Is there any way to stealthy kill a heavy gunner or heavy flame unit without a silenced weapon?

Tags: far-cry-4

I am clearing outposts and am trying to do them silently.  There are times that I am not able to silently disable the alarms without alerting a few soldiers.   So far I haven't found a good way to silently take down heavy units without a silenced weapon - so I have been clearing everyone else in the camp and leaving the heavy units last.   Is there anyway to silently take them down without a silenced weapon?  Takedowns aren't an option and arrows just bounce off of them.

I haven't unlocked silenced weapons yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not without unlocking Heavy Beatdown, which must be unlocked by destroying a convoy. That skill will allow you to perform takedowns on Heavies. As you say, arrows bounce off.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. I see I need to do Destroy 1 Pagan's Wrath convoy